# How to get checked and unchecked value with jQuery live?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5-canvas

I have three checkbox. Screenshot given bellow.

[image]

I am trying to do that - when check boxes are not checked it will show 0+0+0.

When the checkbox will checked it will change the value.

Suppose I checked Breakfast then it will show 1+0+0

Again suppose I checked Breakfast and Lunch it will show 1+1+0

Again suppose I checked all the checkbox it will show 1+1+1

I can't understand how I can do that.

Anyone can help me to solve this.

My html code

```
<ul id="checkboxes" class="list-unstyled list-inline">
    <li class="list-inline-item">
        <div class="checkbox-custom checkbox-primary">
            <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="BRK_FST">
            <label>Breakfast</label>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="list-inline-item">
        <div class="checkbox-custom checkbox-primary">
            <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="LUNCH" >
            <label>Lunch</label>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="list-inline-item">
        <div class="checkbox-custom checkbox-primary">
            <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="DINNER">
            <label>Dinner</label>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="list-inline-item">
        <div id="output"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Where's your javascript? Please post full snippet

Comment: I haven't write it yet @IslamElshobokshy

Comment: This site is not a code-writing service, _you_ are supposed to make an initial attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get click action and check if the input if checked or not.

```js
$('input[name="BRK_FST"]').click(function() {
  var active = $(this).prop("checked") ? 1 : 0;
  $('.BRK_FST').text(active);
  console.log(active);
});

$('input[name="LUNCH"]').click(function() {
  var active = $(this).prop("checked") ? 1 : 0;
  $('.LUNCH').text(active);
  console.log(active);
});

$('input[name="DINNER"]').click(function() {
  var active = $(this).prop("checked") ? 1 : 0;
  $('.DINNER').text(active);
  console.log(active);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="checkboxes" class="list-unstyled list-inline">
    <li class="list-inline-item">
        <div class="checkbox-custom checkbox-primary">
            <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="BRK_FST">
            <label>Breakfast</label>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="list-inline-item">
        <div class="checkbox-custom checkbox-primary">
            <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="LUNCH">
            <label>Lunch</label>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="list-inline-item">
        <div class="checkbox-custom checkbox-primary">
            <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="DINNER">
            <label>Dinner</label>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="list-inline-item">
        <div id="output"></div>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="result">
  <span class="BRK_FST">0</span>+<span class="LUNCH">0</span>+<span class="DINNER">0</span>
</div>
```

Comment: How can fetch it to <div id="output"></div> just like 1+1+0 or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a simple JQuery code like this:

```
$("input").click(function(){
    let outputText = ""; // stores output text

    $("#output").empty(); // delete content of output element

    if($(this).is(":checked")){ // check if the clicked element is checked
         $(this).val("1"); // change the value to 1
    }else{ // if not ckecked
        (this).val("0"); // change the value to 0
    }

    $("input").map((i, inputElement)=>{
        outputText += $(inputElement).val()+" "; // add the value of each input to the outputText variable created before
    })

   $("#output").html(outputText) // add the outputText string to the output element

})
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.